# Xamarin Android Application traffic sometimes not appearing on Charles Proxy

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, charles-proxy

I am trying to capture the network traffic of a Xamarin Android application in Charles proxy. I am able to see the network calls for user login initially , but after login I am not able to see the calls for other screens . Even-though the Charles is not showing the network calls , it is not blocking the screens from loading .But when I quit and relaunch the app , Sometimes I am able to see the network calls for other screens. The behavior is inconsistent . The app is using AndroidClientHandler for HttpClient implementation.

Please note :- I am seeing network traffic for iOS without any issues.[image]

Comment: Charles only supports the HTTP/HTTPS protocol. If your network call protocol is not this, it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

The AndroidClientHandler only recently got proxy support https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/commit/bf0704496ac5cd5df5c82822048fe07ac6923971

One limitation is that it does not pick up System proxy per default. So you will have to supply it yourself:

```
var handler = new AndroidClientHandler 
{
    UseProxy = true,
    Proxy = new WebProxy
    {
        Address = new Uri("http://10.0.0.2:7000")
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi Cheesebaron , But I am seeing network calls in Charles proxy seldom , But most of the times I am not able to see the network calls .